# A question involving norms

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $(X, \| \cdot \|_X), (Y, \| \cdot \|_Y)$ be normed spaces and $T : X \rightarrow Y$ a bounded operator. Let $x, y \in X$ and let the norm on $X$
$$ \|x\| = \|x\|_X + \|Tx\|_Y. $$
I can't show that if
$$ \|x + y\|= \|x\| + \|y\| \hspace{20pt} (1)$$
then
$$ \|Tx + Ty\|_Y = \|Tx\|_Y + \|Ty\|_Y. $$
From $(1)$ we have
$$ \|x + y\|_X + \|Tx + Ty\|_Y = \|x\|_X + \|y\|_X + \|Tx\|_Y + \|Ty\|_Y. $$
And then?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. Since $$ \|x\|_X + \|y\|_X + \|Tx\|_Y + \|Ty\|_Y = \|x + y\|_X + \|Tx + Ty\|_Y$$
and 
$$ \|x+y\|_X \le \|x\|_X + \|y\|_Y$$
you have
$$\|x\|_X + \|y\|_X + \|Tx\|_Y + \|Ty\|_Y \le  \|x\|_X + \|y\|_Y + \|Tx + Ty\|_Y.$$
Now cancel to get $\|Tx\|_Y + \|Ty\|_Y \le \|Tx + Ty\|_Y$.

Comment: It should be added (even if it's obvious): the reverse inequality holds by the triangle inequality.